# Meteor - how can I empty out the collection of 10,000 objects I subscribed to after I no longer need it?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a template in which a user should be able to click on a button to bring up a modal and in the modal choose a handful of items out of a list of about 10,000 items which are displayed there to search or scroll through.

Since this collection is so big, I don't want to keep it around in memory when I don't absolutely need it.

So I would like to subscribe to this collection only when the modal is being viewed and I would like to ensure that I am unsubscribed if the modal is not being viewed.

Is there a way to explicitly unsubscribe from a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe

Quoting the docs :

> Meteor.subscribe returns a subscription handle, which is an object
>   with the following methods:
>
> stop() Cancel the subscription. This will typically result in the
>   server directing the client to remove the subscription's data from the
>   client's cache.

So basically what you need to do is storing the subscription handle in a variable and call the `stop` method when you don't need those published documents anymore.

Note that if you're using `iron:router` (and you probably should), this is taken care of automatically for you on each route change, which is convenient but has the side effect of provoking a lot of sometimes unnecessary calls to `Meteor.publish` calls which are non trivial for the server and bandwidth... to address this matter you can use `meteorhacks:subs-manager` but it's another topic anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

1. Use the subscription handle

[subscribe](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) returns a handle you can call `stop` on. For example:

```js
var handle = Meteor.subscribe('stuff');
handle.stop();
```

2. Use an autorun

Because an `autorun` will automatically start and stop subscriptions when its reactive dependencies change, this will work:

```js
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  if (Session.get('showingModal'))
    Meteor.subscribe('stuff');
});
```

Side note - it may make more sense to use a method call for searching such a large data set rather than publishing the entire thing to the client. For example you can set a session variable whenever the user's query changes, then use an `autorun` to update the result set based on the method's return value.